# sql query to show the value of variable in precedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, select, null

I created my DB with microsoft sql server 2012 and now I need to get a value from procedure I'm using this query :

```
begin try
    begin tran
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Insert Into dbo.parents
    (FatherFirstName,FatherLastName,MotherFirstName,MotherLastName,ParentIdNum,VolunteerId,Address)
    values
    (@FFname,@FLname,@MFname,@MLname,@IDnum,@VolunteerId,@add)
    set @returnVal = 'good'
    commit tran
end try

begin catch

    rollback tran

    set @returnVal = 'error!' 

end catch
```

and then I use :

```
declare @param sysname

exec dbo.uspCreateNewParents 1,'xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx',@param
 select @param
```

and all I get is null values and the column name is the value of @param....

please help me how can I retrieve the value of the variable ??!

Comment: The value of what variable?

Comment: Are you declaring `@returnVal` as an `output` variable in your stored procedure? If you can show your whole stored procedure, that would help.

Comment: Please post the stored procedure definition.